# Registration in the git hub, git and the repository problem

Tags: github, repository

I want to make a repository in **GitHub** for the first time and now it gives me this error

```
Username for 'https://github.com': ******`enter username here`
Password for 'https://m.erfanpld@github.com': `enter password here`
remote: Permission to MErfanPld/web.git denied to MErfanPld.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/MErfanPld/web.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: GitHub stopped accepting passwords for https cloning. You must now use a [GitHub Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) instead. This is specific to GitHub; it's not a *Git* feature (Git does not have authentication on its own). As [BobyCloud answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69401880/1256452), you can also use ssh; I personally prefer ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can access Github repositories when they are private.

1. HTTPS
2. SSH

I recommend the second method, You must create an ssh key using the command below

```
ssh-keygen
```

Now You can print Your ssh public key using the command bellow in Linux

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Use [this link](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-view-your-ssh-keys-in-linux-macos-and-windows/) as a hint to manage your ssh keys.

Finally, you need to add your public ssh key into GitHub, Github explains this [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) with a picture guide. Now through ssh public key and without the need to log in with a username and password every single time, You can access your private repositories in a secure way.

Best regards